# Encourage the newcomers

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask is if is a good practice to encourage the newcomers.

This would be:

- simple pointers, to analyze more and improve the question quality
- provide links to some rules
- words of encouragement, and directions to stay persistent

***Let me make one thing very clear:*** With this I am certainly not forbidding anyone to down-vote, just asking for the additional hold before down-vote.

**Summary** :

If we manage to make this platform look more attractive to the newcomers, I am sure this will result in something good.

Comment: While I am completely on your side and support your commitment, I have one note: This is **not** a forum…

Comment: correct, thanks to the Wikipedia I am using the platform word from now on.

Comment: I am a newcomer. If I ran the world I'd say if someone asks a simple question without posting any code whatsoever it should be ok to post a simple reply, telling them what to search for. Otherwise, do not allow simple questions with no code. It seems crazy to me that a question that has had almost no effort put into it needs someone to put a lot of time into writing a detailed answer.

Comment: that is true. I fully understand you. and I can say the same for the spammers. today I saw them. You always have to option to set that as a spam, as I learned today. And for the bad quality questions, you can flag them. But what is the use of down-voting someone with 1 point?

Comment: for bad quests, you can flag them and ask for details and more effort. so ask for effort before providing it.

Comment: @prosti [What purpose does downvoting questions serve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/what-purpose-does-downvoting-questions-serve)

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ, as I am still learning about the platform, I cannot comment  well and in good quality on that question. But, one can flag a spam or low-quality question, or any kind of other junk, and admins may remove that. However, downvoting, newcomer as low as -3, -4, -5 may end in bad first-time experience.

Comment: @prosti that is why you should always review a site's guidelines before making a question.  We have the [tour] and [ask] that should be referenced before asking.  Sadly, SE is a learning curve but as already stated there are several that basically expect free work and ask questions with no effort.  If an edit is ever made the votes can be reversed.  So downvoting serves several purposes, 1) encourages the OP to make an edit, 2) informs others this question is frowned upon 3) if a question is closed and has several downvotes SE purges the question after 3 months.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ: I understand you, and the smart question you asked first, I understood that also. As I said, I am relatively new to the platform. And I can only suggest, you add another flag as `free work` or so. I am also thankful to you for providing these links. We cannot expect all the visitors to this website will read the manuals first before asking the question and more, to understand them in a perfect way.

Comment: you can also link them automatically in a comment without adding the URLs to the information: `[ask]` -> [ask]; `[tour]` -> [tour]; `[edit]` -> [edit]

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ I am agree with @prosti. When new users come in site then they don't have any clue, this site has even guidelines. New users never explore all menu options, they will see only those option that are clearly visible in front of their eyes like `Ask Question' button. And without thinking anything else they will click on it. So it would be too much to expect from any new user to read guidelines first, since its not directly visible option. If viewing guidelines before asking question is really that important then that option must be visible in first look Either by popup on ask Q. page.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ And most importantly when new user comes then we suppose to welcome them. Even if he/she asked question in inappropriate way then to tell him/her about his/her bad question one down vote is sufficient. He can guess his question is not good by seeing one down vote But no need to -3 or -5 down votes. This will surely discourage them to visit the site again. In short, show some respect to new users instead of showing attitude by gifting them bunch of down votes. Human brain can understand one down vote is for what!

Comment: @Rishabh after several communications with new users I am hesitant at times trying to explain to new users was is and isn't acceptable as I'm tired of arguing, Ive been cussed at, and even when I send the documentation on what is in scope at times that doesn't help.  Furthermore, your comment perpetuates what many of said, and that's people visit a site without looking at the rules. you may also see: [Let's Plan the Second Iteration of the Stack Exchange Quality Project!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project)

Comment: As comments are temporary and this discussion is not per SE guidelines as it is a discussion, if you'd like to continue this I would encourage us to discuss this in chat, if you would like to please feel free to ping me, in chat.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ `your comment perpetuates `. But if people visit site without looking guidelines then there is a reason behind it (that I have explained in prev. comment). IMHO Best option to stop this from happening is, When visitor first time goes to "Ask Question" page then there should be a popup appear in which written "before asking question you should see our site's guidelines to know what you can ask or what you cannot. If you continue without looking for guidelines then you may get "down votes" and your question may get rejected by community". And also provide link of guidelines in popup.

Comment: As pointed to, I think that is in in the first [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285903/214917) of the Q&A I linked above.